# Printed Null values in Java Caching System(JCS)

Tags: java, jcs

I tried to implement the java caching system using (JCS).I learned from some websites and tried to implement them.Here are some of my configuration:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.ashwin</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcsprojectone</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>jcsprojectone</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jcs/jcs -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jcs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcs</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/concurrent/concurrent -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>concurrent</groupId>
      <artifactId>concurrent</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.4</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Main app.java class

```
package com.ashwin.jcsprojectone;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(new FileInputStream("src/log4j.properties"));
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);

            MusicStore musicStore = new MusicStore();
            musicStore.addAlbum(new Album(4, "The O.C. Supertones",
                    "Supertones Strike Back"));
            Album album = musicStore.getAlbum(1);
            System.out.println("Album 1: " + album);
            album = musicStore.getAlbum(4);
            System.out.println("Album 4: " + album);
            musicStore.removeAlbum(4);
            album = musicStore.getAlbum(4);
            System.out.println("Album 4: " + album);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Album.java

```
package com.ashwin.jcsprojectone;

public class Album implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Integer id;
    private String artist;
    private String title;

    public Album() {
    }

    public Album( Integer id, String artist, String title ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId( Integer id ) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist( String artist ) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle( String title ) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return artist + ": " + title;
    }
}
```

MusicStore.java

```
package com.ashwin.jcsprojectone;

import org.apache.jcs.JCS;
import org.apache.jcs.access.exception.CacheException;
import org.apache.jcs.engine.control.CompositeCacheManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.util.Properties;


public class MusicStore {

    private JCS cache;

    public MusicStore() {
        try {
            CompositeCacheManager ccm = CompositeCacheManager.getUnconfiguredInstance();
            Properties props = new Properties();

            props.put("jcs.default","DC");
            props.put("jcs.default.cacheattributes",
                    "org.apache.jcs.engine.CompositeCacheAttributes");
// lots more props.put - this is basically the contents of cache.ccf
            Logger log
                    = Logger.getLogger(MusicStore.class);
            // Load the cache
            cache = JCS.getInstance("musicCache");

            // Initialize the cache
            cache.put(new Integer(1),
                    new Album(1, "Toby Mac", "Diverse City"));
            cache.put(new Integer(2),
                    new Album(2, "Pillar", "Fireproof"));
            cache.put(new Integer(3),
                    new Album(3, "Audio Adrenaline", "Underdog"));
        } catch (CacheException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void addAlbum(Album album) {
        try {
            cache.put(album.getId(), album);
        } catch (CacheException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Album getAlbum(Integer id) {
        return (Album) cache.get(id);
    }

    public void removeAlbum(Integer id) {
        try {
            cache.remove(id);
        } catch (CacheException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have configured cache.ccf and log4j.properties file as:
[image]

I dont know whether I had putted these files in correct path and are loaded in codes properly.At first,there was no file found error ,so I moved int src folder and confgured in codes.

cache.ccf

```
# DEFAULT CACHE REGION
jcs.default=DC
jcs.default.cacheattributes=
     org.apache.jcs.engine.CompositeCacheAttributes
jcs.default.cacheattributes.MaxObjects=1000
jcs.default.cacheattributes.MemoryCacheName=
     org.apache.jcs.engine.memory.lru.LRUMemoryCache
jcs.default.cacheattributes.UseMemoryShrinker=true
jcs.default.cacheattributes.MaxMemoryIdleTimeSeconds=3600
jcs.default.cacheattributes.ShrinkerIntervalSeconds=60
jcs.default.elementattributes=org.apache.jcs.engine.ElementAttributes
jcs.default.elementattributes.IsEternal=false
jcs.default.elementattributes.MaxLifeSeconds=21600
jcs.default.elementattributes.IdleTime=1800
jcs.default.elementattributes.IsSpool=true
jcs.default.elementattributes.IsRemote=true
jcs.default.elementattributes.IsLateral=true
```

log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, DebugAppender

#Debug logging
log4j.appender.DebugAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.File=activityLog.log
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.MaxFileSize=200KB
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{DATE} %t - %m%n
```

But my project runs successfully but the Null is printed in output as:

```
null

Process finished with exit code 0
```

There is nothing printed in output except this value.Why is no my output coming?